# Mix and precentage in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have about 100k rows and need to classify them by precentage
For ex
The top 1%
The second 4%
The third 5%
1% means to give me the 1% of the total of rows

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum <= cnt * 0.01 then 'Top 1%'
             when seqnum <= cnt * 0.05 then 'Top 5%'
             else 'Everything else'
        end) as grp
from (select t.*, count(*) over () as cnt,
             rank() over (order by ?) as seqnum 
      from t
     ) t
```

`?` is the column that specifies the ordering you care about -- what "top 1%" means.

MySQL also has `PERCENT_RANK()` which calculate the value directly -- so you don't have to do the division.